# Devise gem and two steps sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Is there any way to sign in with two steps using Devise? I would like to allow users sign in using two steps, maybe sending an e-mail to users with a code.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you're looking for is called [Multi-Factor Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication). The recommended way to do this with Devise (via the Devise wiki) is [Houdini](https://github.com/Houdini/two_factor_authentication)

Comment: No problem, if that resolves your question, can you select an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Confirmable: sends emails with confirmation instructions and verifies whether an account is already confirmed during sign in.

http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable

Like this??

Comment: Hi Bob, not like that. I'm looking for what Momer sad. Thanks